# awk delete duplicate

Tags: awk

I want to determine if a record contains a duplicate value for a specific field and then delete the duplicate record and save the new file.

```
abc|123|def|456
abc|456|ghi|789
def|123|def|456
```

I want to save a new file with any record that duplicates field 1 removed.

```
abc|123|def|456
def|123|def|456
```

This awk code comes close, but actually does the opposite.  It creates a new duplicate row and then saves it to the new file.

```
awk -F'|' 'myv=a[$1] !/^myv++/' file.txt > newFile.txt
```

Comment: `awk -F'|' '!a[$1]++' file.txt > newFile.txt`

Comment: oops, this is the code that comes close -- awk -F'|' 'myv=a[$1]++ !/^myv/' file.txt > newFile.txt ------  with the ++ to catch duplicates. but I do not want to then add the duplicate lines, i want to remove them.

Comment: SOLVED - thank you steeldriver -- why did you submit that as a comment when it is the answer?  I want to give you credit.

Comment: Thanks - I posted it as a comment because I'm convinced it must be a duplicate of a previous question (although I can't quite find it)

Comment: @StephenKitt That one is slightly different; it doesn't print the whole line.

Comment: @Sparhawk I reckoned the important part was the array incrementing technique; but your suggestion is better, thanks!